# how to get a value of a specific attribute from xml

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

in c, I have this xml :

```
<apStats><command chart_num="0">750</command><command chart_num="1">400</command></apStats>
```

.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml", 
    url: getUrl('/GetPeriodicStats/'), 
    data: XML.innerHTML,//stats_requests,
    success: function(c){

$(c).find('command').each(function(){
              //i want here to look for the value of command with attribute chart_num="0" . What should I write ?
                });
            });
```

I wrote in the code my question

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop, just use the attribute selector and get the text

```
$(c).find('command[chart_num=0]').text()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!
instead of a scalar (750 or 400 here), command can have sons..
Is there a way to check if it has sons ?

Comment: about :  $(c).find('command[chart_num=0]').text()
I need to make it an integer, how can I do that ?

Comment: [**parseInt**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book');

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
document.write(x[i].getAttribute('category'));
document.write("<br>");
}
```

Link

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp

Answer (score 0):

I  think you should try the following code this will help you find the attribute name "chart_num".

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml", 
url: getUrl('/GetPeriodicStats/'), 
data: XML.innerHTML,//stats_requests,
success: function(c){

$(c).find('command').each(function(i)
{
   //look for the value of command with attribute chart_num="0"
     if($(this).attr("command")=="0")
     {
      alert("Chart 0 Found");   
     }
    });
 });
```

Comment: why is the 'i' needed ?

Comment: Its ok if u don't use its like function(object) so i use "i" instead of "object".